# How to use req and res inside socket express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

How to use req and res inside socket express.js (Node)

```
module.exports = function (io) {

   io.use(function(socket, next){
      if (socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.token){
        jwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, 'SECRET_KEY', function(err, decoded) {
          if (err) return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
          socket.decoded = decoded;


          /*
            Can i use here req and res here ?

            i.e req.constant
            req.constant is my middleware that 
          */

          next();
        });
      }
      else {
        next(new Error('Authentication error'));
      }    
    })
    .on('connection', function(socket) {
        // Connection now authenticated to receive further events

        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            io.emit('message', message);
        });
  }
```

This is another file where I put these values

```
let connection = async(req, res, next) =>{
    req.constants = require('../constants');
    next();
}
```

If i do write io.use(function(req, res, socket, next){ }

that does not work if i access it directly it does not work how can i use  it ? Please guide on this req.constant should get called

Thanks

Comment: do you want to associate a value with the connection object ? What exactly you want to achieve by `req.constants = require('../constants')` ?

Comment: Yes, I want the value that associates with req.constants inside socket but when I place req.constants inside socket it says req is not defined

Comment: try `socket.constants = require('../constants')`

Comment: I guess then socket is undefined I am going to get isn't ?

Comment: you have already done that `socket.decoded = decoded;` try it out

Comment: Unlike REST where is connection is alive through out the request only, hence we have those objects.. where as in sockets the connection is persistent so whatever attribute you set, will be available as long as connection is alive.